# Move element to first position in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting, object

I have an object like this:

```
var data = [
    { id: "fmgbwe45", age: 24, gender: "male"   },
    { id: "kjregh23", age: 27, gender: "female" }, 
    { id: "kjfdhg87", age: 30, gender: "male" }, 
    { id: "lsdjfk43", age: 10, gender: "female" }, 
]
```

I want to sort the object, this is my 
expected output:

```
var data = [
    { id: "kjfdhg87", age: 30, gender: "male" },  //only one record will match in my sort
    { id: "fmgbwe45", age: 24, gender: "male"   },
    { id: "kjregh23", age: 27, gender: "female" }, 
    { id: "lsdjfk43", age: 10, gender: "female" }, 
]
```

I have tried this:

```
$scope.sort_by = function (newSortingOrder) {
    var stringToFilter = newSortingOrder.toString();   //this holds 'kjfdhg87'
    var obj = data.sort(function(o) { return o.id - stringToFilter; });
    var finalObj = [obj];
    sortedData = finalObj;
    console.log(sortedData ); //sorting is not working as expected where im doing wrong.
}
```

Comment: Do you want to sort by id field ?

Comment: yes i want sort by id, only id.

Comment: Calling this "sorting" is a poor way to describe this. All you are wanting to do is move the entry with a matching `id` into the first position, you are not asking to sort the other entries in the array by any criteria.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Since you are just moving one item to the top, I will just use `splice()` and `unshift()` the item:

```js
var data = [
    { id: "fmgbwe45", age: 24, gender: "male"   },
    { id: "kjregh23", age: 27, gender: "female" }, 
    { id: "kjfdhg87", age: 30, gender: "male" }, 
    { id: "lsdjfk43", age: 10, gender: "female" }, 
]
data.forEach(function(item,i){
  if(item.id === "kjfdhg87"){
    data.splice(i, 1);
    data.unshift(item);
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: it may work, but I do not like this approach because it is manipulating positions in the array while looping through it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `unshift` method.

```js
var data = [
    { id: "fmgbwe45", age: 24, gender: "male"   },
    { id: "kjregh23", age: 27, gender: "female" }, 
    { id: "kjfdhg87", age: 30, gender: "male" }, 
    { id: "lsdjfk43", age: 10, gender: "female" }, 
]

var stringToFilter = 'kjfdhg87';   //this holds 'kjfdhg87'
data.unshift(data.splice(data.findIndex(item => item.id === stringToFilter), 1)[0])
console.log(data);
```

Comment: @Mrworldwide, no, item1 and item2 are elements passed to the callback function for sort function.

Comment: @Mrworldwide, do you want to sort the array but keep the `newSortingOrder` as first ?

Comment: @Mrworldwide, i updated my answer. Please edit your question. This is not a sorting.

Comment: thanks for the help i really appriciate its actually ES5 so im using @mamun answer.

Comment: @Mrworldwide, you can try a more simple solution: `data.sort((a, b)=>{ if(b.id == stringToFilter) return 1;});`

Comment: Perfect answer , Thanks alot !

Answer (score 7):

Here's a different non-mutating approach. I'm using TypeScript just for the Person definition, but other than that is just ES6.

Basically we just need to:

1. Filter out the person from the original array
2. Insert it again at the beginning

```
movePersonInArray(person: Person, arrayOfPersons: Person[]): Person[] {
    // remove the item from the array
    const filteredArrayOfPersons = arrayOfPersons.filter((p: Person) => p.id !== person.id);
    // add it at the beginning
    return [{ ...person }, ...filteredArrayOfPersons];
}
```

If you don't mind mixing things a bit, you can avoid the *spread* operator and use *unshift* instead. I particularly don't like to mix functions that mutate the array with those that don't, but in certain scenarios, you may get some performance improvements. For example, for a very long array, the following change in the original method will speed up things a bit while keeping the legibility.

```
movePersonInArray(person: Person, arrayOfPersons: Person[]): Person[] {
    // remove the item from the array
    const filteredArrayOfPersons = arrayOfPersons.filter((p: Person) => p.id !== person.id);
    // add it at the beginning
    filteredArrayOfPersons.unshift({...person});
    return filteredArrayOfPersons;
}
```

Neither of these two approaches mutates the **arrayOfPersons** array, instead, they return a copy with the changes.
Here you can learn more about array mutation methods
https://doesitmutate.xyz/

PS. The *Person* type can be something like this:

```
export interface Person {
id: string;
name: string;
age: number;
}
```

Peace!

Comment: Thanks:) Nice and clean