# How to move duplicate to first index in an array of Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

I have below variable with array of Objects

```
let Obj1 =

    [
    {Id: 123, name: 'A'},
    {Id: 124, name: 'B'},
    {Id: 125, name: 'C'},
    {Id: 126, name: 'D'},
    {Id: 127, name: 'E'}
    ]

let Obj2 = {Id:126, name: 'D'}
```

How do I move the Obj2 in Obj1 to the 0th index dynamically in Javascript or TypeScript?
Obj2 is from backend and Obj1 is the data already present in frontend
The End result should be as below

```
[
{Id: 126, name: 'D'},
{Id: 123, name: 'A'},
{Id: 124, name: 'B'},
{Id: 125, name: 'C'},
{Id: 127, name: 'E'}
]
```

Comment: The result contains only 5 elements and not 6, is this normal ?

Comment: why is the Id and id spelled inconsistent
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186075/move-element-to-first-position-in-array

Comment: @LucasBodin yes, because I wanna replace one item with another.

Comment: @cmgchess sorry about the typo, I think this would work
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
let Obj1 =
    [
    {id: 123, name: 'A'},
    {id: 124, name: 'B'},
    {id: 125, name: 'C'},
    {id: 126, name: 'D'},
    {id: 127, name: 'E'}
    ];

let Obj2 = {id:126, name: 'D'};

let new_array = Obj1.reduce((curr, acc)=>(acc.id === Obj2.id ? curr.unshift(acc) : curr.push(acc), curr), []);

console.log(new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```js
let Obj1 = [
   {
      "Id":123,
      "name":"A"
   },
   {
      "Id":124,
      "name":"B"
   },
   {
      "Id":125,
      "name":"C"
   },
   {
      "Id":126,
      "name":"D"
   },
   {
      "Id":127,
      "name":"E"
   }
]

let Obj2 = {
    "Id":126, 
    "name":"D"
}

/* 

if Obj2 isn't in the array called Obj1...
put Obj2 at the front of the Obj1 array

*/

if (Obj1.indexOf(Obj2) == -1) {
  Obj1.unshift(Obj2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let Obj1 =

    [
        {Id: 123, name: 'A'},
        {Id: 124, name: 'B'},
        {Id: 125, name: 'C'},
        {Id: 126, name: 'D'},
        {Id: 127, name: 'E'}
    ]

let Obj2 = {Id:126, name: 'D'}

for (let i = 0; i < Obj1.length; i++) {
    if (Obj1[i].Id === Obj2.Id && Obj1[i].name === Obj2.name) {
        Obj1.splice(i, 1)
        Obj1.unshift(Obj2)
        break
    }
}

console.log(Obj1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could sort by checking the properties.

```js
const
    isEqual = (a, b) => a.Id === b.Id && a.name === b.name,
    array = [{ Id: 123, name: 'A' }, { Id: 124, name: 'B' }, { Id: 125, name: 'C' }, { Id: 126, name: 'D' }, { Id: 127, name: 'E' }],
    object = { Id: 126, name: 'D' };

array.sort((a, b) => isEqual(b, object) - isEqual(a, object));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This Worked for me
Thanks

```
data.unshift(data.splice(data.findIndex(item => item.Id === Obj2.Id, 1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to move the `Obj2` at the first index in the `Obj1`. Descriptive comments has been added in the below code snippet.

You can try this **:**

```js
// Input array
let Obj1 = [
  {Id: 123, name: 'A'},
  {Id: 124, name: 'B'},
  {Id: 125, name: 'C'},
  {Id: 126, name: 'D'},
  {Id: 127, name: 'E'}
];

// Search object
let Obj2 = {Id: 126, name: 'D'};

// Iterate over an original array to move the search object at 0th index.
Obj1.forEach((obj, index) => {
  // Check if Obj2 exist in the array Obj1
    if (JSON.stringify(Obj2) === JSON.stringify(obj)) {
    // Removing the object
    const removedObj = Obj1.splice(index, 1);
    // Inserting the removed object at index 0.
    Obj1.unshift(removedObj);
  }
});

// Output
console.log(Obj1);
```