# Issue removing first element of array with Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

I'm trying to find an element in an array, remove that element if found, and then add that element at the start of the array.

However when I log my array sortedAdv returns as only one element length for some reason

My code:

```
let advantages = [ 'liked', 'sendUnlimitedLikes', 'unlockSundays', 'getBoosted', 'filters', 'revealAllProfiles', 'wholeCountry', 'exlusiveBlogs' ];
 
console.log('advantages', advantages.length);

let index = advantages.findIndex((advantage) => advantage == type);
if (index > -1) {
  console.log('index', index);
  let sortedAdv = advantages.splice(index, 1);
  console.log('sortedAdv', sortedAdv.length);
  sortedAdv.unshift(type);
  console.log('sortedAdv', sortedAdv.length);
  this.setPurchaseAdvantages(sortedAdv);
}
```

Comment: splice returns the removed elements, not the original array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move element to first position in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50186075/move-element-to-first-position-in-array)

Comment: also [Move an array element from one array position to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306680/move-an-array-element-from-one-array-position-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

you are geting an array when you are using this

```
let removedElement = advantages.splice(index, 1);
```

```
let advantages = ['liked', 'sendUnlimitedLikes', 'unlockSundays', 'getBoosted', 'filters', 'revealAllProfiles', 'wholeCountry', 'exlusiveBlogs'];
let type = 'getBoosted'; 
let index = advantages.indexOf(type); // Find the index of the element
if (index > -1) {
  let removedElement = advantages.splice(index, 1)[0]; // Remove the element and store it
  advantages.unshift(removedElement); // Add the element to the start of the array
}

console.log(advantages);
```